# Count Values associated with key in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three tables

Table Category

```
CategoryID         Category
1                   Climate
2                   Area
```

Table CategoryDetail

```
DetailID    CategoryID      Desc
1            1              Hot
2            1              Cold
3            2              Area1
```

Table CategoryDetailValues

```
PK  AnotherFK  CategoryDetailID
1    1           1
2    1           1
3    1           2
4    2           1
```

Here AnotherFK is foreign key referring to another table. In record 1 and 2 duplicate exists that's ok but AnotherFK 1 has reference of CategoryDetailID 1 and 2 which has categoryID of 1 which is not ok

So from above tables
this result is valid from above three table

```
PK   AnotherFK    CategoryID  DetailID     Desc
1    1             1            1          Hot
2    1             1            1          Hot
```

But below result is not valid

```
PK   AnotherFK    CategoryID  DetailID     Desc
2    1             1           1           Hot
3    1             1           2           Cold
```

I can not put same AnotherFK in two different DetailID which has same CategoryID. I could have eliminated this by introducing CategoryID in CategoryDetailValues table and creating unique constraint but I am not allowed to do so.

Now my aim is to find all those record in CategoryDetailValues table which has different DetailID that are associated with same CategoryID. So that I can delete them.

Trying to achieve this in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What RDBSMS are you using? You tagged it with 2 versions of SQL Server as well as MySQL.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Please stop adding tags.

Comment: The problem is with your datamodel. If a detail should only have one Value, then you can add the AnotherFK column to CategoryDetail and drop the CategoryDetailValues table.

Comment: @Peter thats the problem I am trying to eliminate. Since exact duplicate record doesn't create problem as they will be eliminated on latter stage but those record that have same CategoryID and different DetailID will cause the problem and I new to know how may AnotherFK has same CategoryID fro different DetailID so that I can delete those.

Comment: Why is "Cold" wrong and "Hot" good? Seems like it could have been the other way around aswell.

Comment: Just to understand this completely: An additional entry with AnotherFK=1 and DetailID=3 would be okay, because that's another CategoryID, correct? Only DetailID=1 and DetailID=2 for AnotherFK=1 are regarded a problem, as they make contradictory statements regarding AnotherFK=1  + CategoryID=1. Yes?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes AnotherFK can have multiple DetailID as long as multiple DetailID doesn't refeere to same CategoryID.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to highlight all AnotherFK cases that have the same CategoryID, but differenty DetailIDs, the following ought to do the trick (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT AnotherFK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY AnotherFK, CategoryID) AS rn FROM #myTable) AS a 
WHERE rn > 1
```

Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable
(
  AnotherFK int
  , CategoryID int
  , DetailID int
  ) ;

  INSERT INTO #myTable (
  AnotherFK 
  , CategoryID 
  , DetailID 
  )
  VALUES (1, 1, 1)
  ,  (1, 1, 2);


  SELECT * FROM (SELECT AnotherFK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AnotherFK, CategoryID) AS rn FROM #myTable) AS a 
  WHERE rn > 1

  DROP TABLE #myTable
```

If this is not what you are after, please elaborate

Comment: that query ranked what I was looking for but also it did exactly similar for all duplicate row. Try to insert 1,1,1 both time and still it shows 2 in rn but I want only 1 for duplicate but 2 for above your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

Script to create sample tables:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   PK               INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,AnotherFK        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,CategoryDetailID INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (2,1,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (3,1,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (4,2,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (5,1,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (6,1,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(PK,AnotherFK,CategoryDetailID) VALUES (7,1,3);

CREATE TABLE mytable2(
   DetailID   INTEGER  NOT NULL   
  ,CategoryID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Descr       VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
```

Query to show "suspect" record (I think you have to decide what records delete...):

```
SELECT *  FROM (
SELECT * ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID, ANotherFK) AS X
, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID, DetailID, ANotherFK) AS X1
FROM mytable A
INNER JOIN mytable2 B ON A.CategoryDetailID= B.DetailID
)C
WHERE X-X1 >0
```

Output:

```
+--+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+-------+---+----+
|  | PK | AnotherFK | CategoryDetailID | DetailID | CategoryID | Descr | X | X1 |
+--+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+-------+---+----+
|  |  1 |         1 |                1 |        1 |          1 | Hot   | 3 |  2 |
|  |  2 |         1 |                1 |        1 |          1 | Hot   | 3 |  2 |
|  |  3 |         1 |                2 |        2 |          1 | Cold  | 3 |  1 |
+--+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+-------+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will look in Categorydetail for records with duplicate DetailID. Than join the tables to provide you the details. It's still up to you to decide which records should be deleted.

```
select * 
from(
    Select CategoryID
    from CategoryDetail
    group by CategoryID
    having count(DetailID)>1)aggr
join CategoryDetail c on aggr.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
join CategoryDetailValues v on c.CategoryDetailID = v.CategoryDetailID
```

Answer (score 0):

You want one value per AnotherFK and Category. So the third table should have a composite key:

- CategoryDetailValues(AnotherFK, CategoryID, DetailID, HowMany)

with a unique constraint on AnotherFK, CategoryID and both building a foreign key to CategoryDetail(CategoryID, DetailID).

In order to clean up data first, you'd have to look for ambiguities:

```
select AnotherFK, CategoryID, DetailID
from
(
  select 
    cdv.AnotherFK, cd.CategoryID, cdv.DetailID,
    count(distinct cd.DetailID) over (partition by cdv.AnotherFK, cd.CategoryID) as cnt
  from CategoryDetailValues cdv
  join CategoryDetail cd on cd.DetailID = cdv.CategoryDetailID
)
where cnt > 1
order by AnotherFK, CategoryID, DetailID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution that comes with following assumption: `within CDV table, for every [AnotherFK] value (ex. 1) should be displayed only those rows with the minimum [CategoryDetailID] (ex. 1)`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT cdv.PK, cdv.AnotherFK, cd.CategoryID, cd.[Desc],
        Rnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cdv.AnotherFK ORDER BY cdv.CategoryDetailID)
    FROM dbo.CategoryDetailValues cdv
    JOIN dbo.CategoryDetail cd ON cd.DetailID = cdv.DetailID
    WHERE cdv.AnotherFK = 1
) x
WHERE x.Rnk = 1
```